# migration spring-boot 1 to spring-boot 2.2.5, used JSP

Tags: spring-boot

I'm looking to make JSP work in Spring Boot 2.
This is a port of an application running on an old version of Spring Boot 1.

This app worked very well. But as soon as I migrated to Spring Boot 2 .. impossible to access the JSP page (the mapping is done well but impossible to find the JSP !!)

This application ships with tomcat and is delivered as a JAR.

Could someone help me or give me an example?

Comment: Hi, did you get it to work? I am using SB 2.2.5 and it cannot access JSP with tomcat

Comment: hi, jsp and jar is incompatible. I switched to thymleaf;).